# spark-shell resolves a loopback address

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I ran the spark-shell but failed.

```
2019-11-03 01:13:55,602 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, localhost resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.1.104 instead (on interface en0)
2019-11-03 01:13:55,604 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform 
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I expect the shell is normal.

Comment: I haven't checked this in a while, but I suspect you need to run Spark on java 8 (illegal access errors are reported by java 9+). The first lines are just warnings. (the title of your question should probably be based on the `ExceptionInInitializerError` failure)